# Annotations from javax.validation.constraints not working (ignored)

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, annotations, constraints

I'm trying to use javax constraints to pre-validate a request content before running the logic.

I have tried any possible solution out there but still can't put javax annotations to work in a Spring boot.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Min
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern

data class LoginRequest (
        @Credential //Custom constraint that works just fine
        val credential: String,

        @Min(value= 5)
        val password: String,

        @Pattern(regexp = Constants.Regex.DEVICE_ID_REGEX, message = "Invalid device ID")
        val device: String
): Serializable
```

This is a part of pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
.
.
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.17.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.17.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is the controller

```
import javax.validation.Valid


@PostMapping("/login")
    fun userLoginEndpoint(@Valid @RequestBody loginRequest: LoginRequest): ResponseEntity<User> {
        return authService.loginUser(loginRequest)
                ?.let{ ResponseEntity(it, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)}
                ?: ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build()
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Replace `@Min(value= 5)`(and the other validation annotations too, of course) by `@field:Min(value= 5)`.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, it worked! Thanks! However I still don't understand how this could be a difference. Any clues?

Comment: If you don't specify `@field`, then what is annotated is the constructor argument AFAIK. But Spring validates the object, once it has been constructed. So what needs to be annotated is the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From @JBNizet comment**

Replace `@Min(value= 5)` (and the other validation annotations too, of course) by `@field:Min(value= 5)`.